Is there any way of moving different node handles in inkscape 1.4?
I've been using inkscape for a while and now I was wondering if it was possible to move two handle nodes that are contiguous to the base nodes at the same time, It would be better if I upload an image:

Is there a way of moving the angle of those contiguous handles at the same proportion?
Because I tried it and this is what happened

As you can see the handles have not moved proporcional and one of them is longer than the other

These are the options that I have active in the node tool
If it's not possible to move the handles proportionally by dragging them, is it possible to change their angles and lengths manually?
By kind please It's my first time posting a question in a forum <3

A workaround: Use grid and have snapping to grid ON.
Or draw some auxiliary lines to help the handle movements. If you have snap to nodes ON the handles also snap. An example:

The starting point is the circle converted to 4 node path as in your example.
The red cord line is drawn between the nodes. The line is duplicated and the duplicate (green) is rotated 90 degrees by clicking the info bar rotate 90 degrees icon.
The red line is scaled shorter by holding Ctrl+Shift keys to keep the line direction. Then it's moved a little. Having snapping to midpoints ON ensures you can place the midpoint on the green line.
The handles are dragged to the ends of the red line.
You can iterate the look by moving and scaling the red line and adjusting the handles again. There's no handy way to snap a line to an existing handle, so adjusting at first one handle to cause the right curvature at one side cannot be easily duplicated exactly. One can use extension Visualize Path > Draw handles as a (clunky) workaround.
The node tool moves the dragging point of a path. If you have made the green line and sent it to back at first and you have snap to path ON you can drag the midpoint of your curve segment along the green line. The handles follow.
If you have zoomed in the method can well produce a result which is accurately enough the wanted one. Zoom in is needed. Otherwise you do not succeed in dragging just the crossing of the curve segment and the green line.

Thank you! This helped me solve my doubt and achieve what I needed.

Dragging a nodes around a circle like that isn't possible in any vector software AFAIK. When you convert a circle to paths, Inkscape doesn't know it's a circle, and doesn't know how you want to place the nodes or modify the handles as you drag.
Instead, you could use the Nodes tool. Double click on the path to add a new node. Then select and delete the other node.  When you delete a node, Inkscape will try its best to maintain a curve.
An example

Note: If you want to add nodes at an exact halfway point between two or more nodes, then with the Nodes tool active, you can select nodes, and use the insert new node button.


Thank you a lot for your time and knowledge. Your response was helpful, but not exactly what I was looking for.

@SusAngel - that's because what you want to do is not actually possible in any vector image editor, at least not the way you imagine. That's just not how they work. All you have here are workarounds.
